# django unexpected amount of queries executed

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

given `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    menu_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MenuEntry(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey("menu", null=True, blank=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("menuentry", null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

when execuring in another file `draw_menu.py` the following:

```
from django import template
from menu.models import MenuEntry
from django.db import connection


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def draw_menu_tag(menu_name):
    queryset = MenuEntry.objects.raw("WITH RECURSIVE \
my_menu_items \
AS( \
SELECT * FROM menu_menuentry WHERE menu_menuentry.menu_id=(SELECT id FROM \
menu_menu WHERE name=%s) \
UNION \
SELECT m.* FROM menu_menuentry m \
INNER JOIN my_menu_items r ON m.parent_id = r.id \
WHERE m.parent_id IS NOT NULL \
) \
SELECT * FROM my_menu_items mmi INNER JOIN menu_menu mm ON mm.id = mmi.menu_id", ["menu_B"])
    q = list(queryset)
    resulting_html = str(queryset_to_dict(q))
    breakpoint()
    
    return 'resulting_html'


def queryset_to_dict(queryset):
    out_dict = {}
    out_dict['menu'] = queryset[0].menu.name
    out_dict['menu_url'] = queryset[0].menu.menu_url
    num_queries = len(connection.queries)
    print(f"Number of queries executed: {num_queries}")
    return out_dict
```

when loading the page with the tag, I get "Number of queries executed: 2". This following gives an extra query

```
    out_dict['menu'] = queryset[0].menu.name
```

But I have joined the corresponding menu items. It should be retrieved without any extra queries.
Please help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a raw queryset, and it seems that Django is not recognising that you've joined the fields in raw SQL. The docs certainly don't mention this as a feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

Try the following code:

```
from django import template
from menu.models import MenuEntry
from django.db import connection


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def draw_menu_tag(menu_name):
    queryset = MenuEntry.objects.raw("WITH RECURSIVE \
my_menu_items \
AS( \
SELECT * FROM menu_menuentry WHERE menu_menuentry.menu_id=(SELECT id FROM \
menu_menu WHERE name=%s) \
UNION \
SELECT m.* FROM menu_menuentry m \
INNER JOIN my_menu_items r ON m.parent_id = r.id \
WHERE m.parent_id IS NOT NULL \
) \
SELECT * FROM my_menu_items mmi INNER JOIN menu_menu mm ON mm.id = mmi.menu_id", ["menu_B"])
    q = list(queryset)
    resulting_html = str(queryset_to_dict(q))
    breakpoint()
    
    return 'resulting_html'


def queryset_to_dict(queryset):
    out_dict = {}
    out_dict['menu'] = queryset[0].name
    out_dict['menu_url'] = queryset[0].menu_url
    num_queries = len(connection.queries)
    print(f"Number of queries executed: {num_queries}")
    return out_dict
```

Note the direct access of `name` and `menu_url`. Although these aren't actual `MenuItem` fields, they're set on the returned model instances by the raw queryset.

Comment: Thanks Dave,
I get this: `AttributeError: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Apologies. Django questions are hard to answer right first time, as you need a whole Django project and database to actually run the code. I've updated my answer to avoid using `.values()`.

Comment: You're right, Dave, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.